# Spring MVC Session delete attribute over multiple requests

Tags: spring-mvc, session, session-variables

i saw here a lot of issues about deletion of session-attributes, which works fine, but it is not what i want. Maybe i misunderstand this.

Problem:
I send two ajax-requests over one session. 
When i send first ajax-request "RequestA", my attribute "AtributeA" will be deleted. I see, that within hattpSession it is not listed anymore. 
When i send second ajax-request "RequestB" to some other handler, i still see my attribute "AtributeA". Even hash-value from this object is the same like in "RequestA". Maybe i make something wrong or it is normal behavior?

My Code  by first ajax-request with Requestmapping: "routeA":

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"ObjectAA"}){
       @RequestMapping("/routeA")
        public handlerAA(HttpSession session){
              session.removeAttribute("ObjektAA"); //Attribute will be deleted as expected
        }

        @RequestMapping("/routeB")
         public handlerBB(HttpSession session){
               session.getAttribute("ObjektAA");
        }
}
```

My Code by second ajax-request with Requestmapping: "routeB":

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"ObjectAA"}){
       @RequestMapping("/routeA")
        public handlerAA(HttpSession session){
              session.removeAttribute("ObjectAA");
        }


        @RequestMapping("/routeB")
         public handlerBB(HttpSession session){
               session.getAttribute("ObjectAA");  //ObjectAA is still in the session? how could it be?
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this spring document, it will clear your problem.

**org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes**

Annotation that indicates the session attributes that a specific handler uses. 
This will typically list the names of model attributes which should be transparently stored in the 
 session or some conversational storage, serving as form-backing beans. Declared at the type level, 
 applying to the model attributes that the annotated handler class operates on. 
NOTE: **Session attributes as indicated using this annotation correspond to a specific handler's model 
 attributes, getting transparently stored in a conversational session. Those attributes will be 
 removed once the handler indicates completion of its conversational session. Therefore, use this 
 facility for such conversational attributes which are supposed to be stored in the session temporarily 
 during the course of a specific handler's conversation. 
For permanent session attributes, e.g. a user authentication object, use the traditional 
 session.setAttribute method instead. Alternatively, consider using the attribute management 
 capabilities of the generic org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest interface.** 
NOTE: When using controller interfaces (e.g. for AOP proxying), make sure to consistently put all 
 your mapping annotations — such as @RequestMapping and @SessionAttributes — on 
 the controller interface rather than on the implementation class.
Since:
     2.5
Author:
     Juergen Hoeller
     Sam Brannen

If you found it helpful mark it as helpful. #happycoding

Comment: Ok, it means, that is normal behavior, that attributes will be removed only on specific handler, and not on over whole browser-session, until browser is closed or i'am logged out.

Comment: hhmm....i just see this documentation and i am confused now:

Using @SessionAttributes to store model attributes in the HTTP session **between ** requests

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib

Thats, what i need, undepend of different requests to retrieve my sesstion-attribute.